# Any way to see ddwrt logs with website/PC names etc?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, dd-wrt

We used to have a dlink dir655 router that had logs in the interface. The logs were simple,easy to read, and had the name of the computers, iphones, etc on it. This made it easy to pinpoint who was doing what or when a device I didn't recognize showed up. 
I have since upgraded to a netgear r7000 and installed ddwrt on it because of all the great things I hear about ddwrt.

I do like ddwrt so far, except for the fact that there's no good way to view logs?

I've tried wallwatcher but had trouble getting that to work correctly on win 8.1. So then tried kiwi, which I have working but it is to busy and confusing to be useful to me at all (at least all I have figured out with it so far)

So basically all I am wondering is if there's any easy way to view logs via ddwrt that is similar to what my dlink used to do?
thx

Comment: There's a question here which may be of interest to you:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98831/converting-webserver-logged-ip-addresses-to-dns